# Regex replace escape character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to build a regex which replaces my escape character. My escape character is a backslash (\). For example:

```
lastname[ct]sam\\\,ple
```

Should get:

```
lastname[ct]sam\,ple
```

First i tried it with this:

```
([\\]{1})(.?)
```

Which matched the correct groups ("\\" and "\,"). Then i tried to just get the backslash with positive lookahead but it didn´t really work out:

```
(?=([\\]{1}[^\\]{1}))(.?)
```

It just matched the backslash before the comma and not the backslash before the backslash. Anybody an idea where my mistake is?

Comment: Did you try [``\\(.)`` to replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/7ho3ll/1)? Match a backslash and capture the subsequent character, and replace with the captured character only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am not sure how to do the substitution on java. I try it!

Comment: In Java: `s.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am simply amazed! Thank you very much! Please post your answer so i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match a backslash and *capture* the subsequent character with [`\\(.)`](https://regex101.com/r/7ho3ll/1) regex, and replace with the captured character only using the `$1` backreference.

In Java, you may use

```
String my_input = "\\\\\\,sample"; // => \\\,sample
String result = my_input.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
System.out.println(result); // => \,sample
```

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nF2tRX).